# Reading from textfile in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have some trouble with reading from text files in GNU Prolog. I want to read a .txt file and move the file to a list. I have tried to follow some previous examples on stackoverflow to read the file, but have not been able to access the file (it seems). Here is what I've got so far:

```
readFile:-
    open('text.txt', read, File),
    read_lines(File, Lines),
    close(File),
    write(Lines), nl.

read_lines(File,[]):- 
    at_end_of_stream(File).

read_lines(File,[X|L]):-
    \+ at_end_of_stream(File),
    read(File,X),
    read_lines(File,L).
```

When I try to call: `?- readFile.` gives me an errormessage: `uncaught exception: error(syntax_error('text.txt:2 (char:1) . or operator expected after expression'),read/2)`.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
As provided by David, GNU Prolog's Character input/output library and get_char worked for me!

Working code:

```
readFile:-
    open('text.txt', read, File),
    read_lines(File, Lines),
    close(File),
    write(Lines), nl.

read_lines(File,[]):- 
    at_end_of_stream(File).

read_lines(File,[X|L]):-
    \+ at_end_of_stream(File),
    get_char(File,X),
    read_lines(File,L).
```

Comment: Could it be that `read/2` expects a Prolog term (_not_ a line of characters) and that your file does not contain that? Does GNU Prolog have [`read_line/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sicstus%3Aread_line/2)?

Comment: The Prolog standard `read/2` predicate reads Prolog **terms**, not lines in a text file. A possible solution is to use Logtalk's [reader](https://logtalk.org/manuals/libraries/reader.html) library, which provides all the necessary predicates for your task, notably `line_to_codes/2-3` predicates. The resulting code will also be fully portable to all Logtalk supported backend Prolog compilers (which naturally includes GNU Prolog).

Comment: @DavidTonhofer no it does not seem like GNU Prolog has read_line/2.

Comment: @PauloMoura do you have an example on how to use Logtalks reader-library? Thanks for both of your replies!

Comment: @RK_97 You will probably have to pass through the logtalk pre-compiler, which is another language. (I like Logtalk, but I'm not ready, Prolog by itself is a deep box of (semi-neglected) tools already). OTOH, you can write another loop to get the characters for a line using GNU Prolog [character input/output](http://gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#sec149)

Comment: Okay, thanks David! I'll check that out instead

Comment: Thanks a lot!! GNU Prolog's get_char(File, Char) worked like magic!

Answer (score 0):

You can improve on your edit answer a bit. First note that the `read_line/2` predicate name is misleading. You're reading a text file  to a list of characters, not to a list of *individual* lines. You're also calling the `at_end_of_stream/1` predicate twice and creating a spurious choice-point at each call to your `read_lines /2` predicate. Moreover, the `at_end_of_stream/1` predicate, albeit a standard predicate, doesn't have a reliable implementation in all Prolog systems. A possible rewrite of your code is:

```
read_file(File, Chars) :-
    open(File, read, Stream),
    get_char(Stream, Char),
    read_file(Stream, Char, Chars),
    close(Stream).

read_file(Stream, Char, Chars) :-
    (   Char == end_of_file ->
        Chars = []
    ;   Chars = [Char| Rest],
        get_char(Stream, Next),
        read_file(Stream, Next, Rest)
    ).
```

Now that your intent is clearer, the same functionality can be accomplished using the Logtalk `reader` library with a single call:

```
reader::file_to_chars(File, Chars)
```

But, if learning is is your primary goal, writing your own solutions instead of relying on existing libraries is a good choice.